# SQLCMD in a for loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, iteration, sqlcmd

I have recently discovered that i am not able to fire the following command from a batch file:

```
for %%G in (%path%) do sqlcmd /S <my-server> /d <my-database> /E /i "%%G" -b
```

It tells me, that it could not find the command "sqlcmd". However, if I run this command directly in the command prompt (by removing one % of each pair) it works!

Why is that and how can I make it work with my batch file?

**Update:**

This is the following code I got in my batch file:

```
@echo off
set mypath=%~dp0
set mypath=%mypath%sql

for %%G in ("%mypath%") do echo %%G & sqlcmd /S sample-server /d sample-database /E /i "%%G" -b

pause
```

Comment: Need to see more of the batch. What have you got before this line?

Comment: this is the whole batch file: http://pastebin.com/bAwM4ukC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
set path=%~dp0
set path="%path%sql\"
```

PATH is the sequence of directories Windows uses to search for executables, so when you change it, `sqlcmd` can no longer be found.

Simply use another variable name. `Mypath` seems good...

Comment: ooh, of course! genius :D i am one step further, seems like sqlcmd is now at least working properly. however, it seems to be having problems with my path (which has got spaces included). `Sqlcmd: 'C:\Dokumente': Invalid file name`

Comment: Try `...sqlcmd.../E /i "%%~G"...` or simply omit the quotes around the `%%G` completely. I believe you'll find `%%G` is already quoted so sql sees `.../E /i ""C:\Dokumente...\sql...""` and can't understand the double-rabbit's ears.

Comment: That was it! Seems like sqlcmd needs quotes though, because it told me it could not find the file "C:\Dokumente" - which is just a part of the full file name. However, with `%%~G` it works flawlessly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for %%i in ("sqlcmd.exe") do "%%~$path:i" /S "my-server" /d "my-database" /E /i "%%~dp$path:i" -b
```

To check your path settings you can use the following code:

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "temppath=%path:;=";"%"
for %%i in ("%temppath%") do echo %%~i
```

Comment: :D i did not use `<my-server>` or `<my-database>` as their names.. i just replaced them to make my code more readable. In fact I just use easy names with letters only ;)

Comment: so it might be necessary to wrap double quotes around the path.

Comment: already did in the variable itself. it seems though, there is no real problem with a wrong path, instead it can't find/execute the command sqlcmd itself.

Comment: well like this it won't iterate through the folder anymore.. eventhough i got 3 files in the folder, it only echoes it once. this is what it echoes: `"" /S "my-server" /d "my-database" /E /i "" -b`

Comment: Please check your `path` settings, you can use the code I posted additional. Try to remove the `echo` command.

Comment: my path got spaces in it, i guess that's maybe why (and with your temppath i get the path echoed out in 3 different lines (makes a new line wherever a space is).

Comment: My code separated the path for better reading, thats OK. If you have foreign characters in the batch file (eg. cyrillic, scandinavic or german "umlaute") please check your batch editor settings, it **must** be saved in DOS/Windows format (codepage OEM 850).

Comment: nope, i haven't - my `%~dp0` is the following: `C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\spzb49e\Desktop` (see pastebin.com/bAwM4ukC)

Comment: To set the path, use `set path=%path%;"%~dp0sql"` (ONLY this line)